# Limit concurrent executions across all function types in Azure Function application

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus

We have a number of Azure Service Bus queues that we consume using Azure Functions with ServiceBusTriggers.

The following setting in host.json limit parallel executions per queue:

```
"extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
        "maxConcurrentCalls": 1
    }
}
```

However since we consume many different queues, this can still trigger many concurrent Azure Function executions that overwhelm our database.

Is there any way to set a global limit for all of the different functions in the application?

Comment: Maybe route those executions into another service bus queue and scale it as need be so as to not throttle your DB?

Comment: @Skin yes if there is no other solution, we might have to do something like that.

Answer (score 3):

`maxConcurrentCalls` is per queue/single trigger. To limit the execution to a single trigger for the entire Functions App, you could use a single trigger in a centralized queue that would get all the messages from the other queues by setting up [Auto Forwarding](https://www.serverless360.com/blog/auto-forwarding-a-hidden-gem-of-service-bus). This way, you producers don't have to change and you'll be processing from a single queue. The downside would be having the logic for different message types in the same function.

Comment: That is interesting. Know any code examples of handling multiple message types in one function?

Comment: I do that in one of the client projects. Using a strategy pattern or some identifier on the message (headers in my case), passing a deserialized of the message to a specific method. I used reflection to automate that aspect. But depending on number of message types, a switch statement could suffice.